# Does Azure AD cookie MW provides sliding sessions

Tags: openid-connect, azure-ad-b2c

I am using OpenId connect protocol for setting up the AzureAD authentication for ASP.NET MVC5 application. After successfully authentication the id_token received by the app during the user authentication transaction will last one hour and hence  the session cookie for the app will also last 1 hour.

Now lets say, I have logged into the application successfully at 8:00 AM ,hence the session cookie will persist until 9:00 AM by default and in the meanwhile, I will be navigating across different areas of the application and doing some kind of action like add,edit and delete and select.

For example, if I submitted a form at 8:30 AM, will the session cookie life time will be extended to 9:30 AM.

I would like to understand whether any actions taken by the user will lead into sliding sessions.

Can anyone correct my understanding here

Answer (score 0):

I think the [Azure AD token lifetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes) doc will help explain quite a bit of this for you. This also demonstrates how you can configure the token and session lifetimes.

The ID token does have 1 hour expiration, at which point you can use a refresh token to silently get a new ID token. If you're just implementing sign in via OIDC middleware, you may not have a refresh token in which case you'll need to rely on the session token being valid for a non-interactive new ID token.

Azure AD does set a session token on the browser that lasts `until-revoked`.  This means that if the tokens did expire, then redirecting to Azure AD may result in new tokens being issued automatically if the session cookie or persistent cookie is valid.

Comment: Can anyone please help me to get thoughts on this scenario:

1. Open the web application using Chrome browser.
2. Navigate to a screen where you do some form post kind of operation. Just fill the data in the form but don’t submit it.
3. Open a new tab of the same application using Chrome browser only
4. Keep working on the second tab continuously


So in that case I would like to know whether the cookie MW provides sliding sessions